# Android: Attaching image to email intent - Error

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I'm trying to attach an image file to send intent (GMail, etc...)
Here's my code:

```
public void mail(ReadableMap options, Callback callback) {
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  i.setType("application/image");

  if (options.hasKey("subject") && !options.isNull("subject")) {
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, options.getString("subject"));
}

if (options.hasKey("body") && !options.isNull("body")) {
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, options.getString("body"));
}

if (options.hasKey("recipients") && !options.isNull("recipients")) {
  ReadableArray r = options.getArray("recipients");
  int length = r.size();
  String[] recipients = new String[length];
  for (int keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < length; keyIndex++) {
    recipients[keyIndex] = r.getString(keyIndex);
  }
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
}

if (options.hasKey("attachment") && !options.isNull("attachment")) {
  ReadableArray r = options.getArray("attachment");
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), r.getString(0)));
//      Log.e("FILE", r.getString(0));
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
}

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Mail");

chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
try {
  reactContext.startActivity(chooser);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  callback.invoke("error");
}
}
```

Log returns:

> 01-19 21:26:52.204 19326-19474/com.nevermind.app E/FILE: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/e461e1a3-b000-4201-8371-00f5e61eca8c.jpg

Image is valid on the device, but it returns error: Can't attach empty file. Rest of the email fields works well on the GMail app.

Here's the output from Android Studio:

> MultiPhoneWindowManager.shouldEnableLayoutInsetsBySoftInput:-1 
>   01-19 21:35:14.864 1225-13155/system_process E/ClipboardUIManager: Failed to get ClipboardService
>   01-19 21:35:14.874 3840-3840/com.google.android.gm E/Gmail: Error adding attachment
>                                                               com.android.mail.utils.b: Cannot attach empty attachment
>                                                                   at com.android.mail.ui.ComposeAttachmentTileGrid.a(SourceFile:62)
>                                                                   at com.android.mail.compose.c.b(SourceFile:2098)
>                                                                   at com.android.mail.compose.c.c(SourceFile:2228)
>                                                                   at com.android.mail.compose.c.a(SourceFile:9157)
>                                                                   at com.android.mail.compose.c.w(SourceFile:833)
>                                                                   at com.android.mail.compose.c.onCreate(SourceFile:5904)
>                                                                   at com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail.onCreate(SourceFile:165)
>                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
>                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6891)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: About which log are you talking when you say 'Log returns:' ? Log.e() ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), r.getString(0)));
```

Change to:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(r.getString(0));
```

R.getSting already contains the full path so no need to get external storage added.